# If array value is empty do not add combiner

Tags: jquery

I have a text combiner where you can add textareas and combine all lines horizontally. You can choose a hyphen you want to put in between the pieces of text. However when a textarea is empty I don't want it to show the hyphens although it currently does. How do I make sure that when a line has an empty value that it doesn't show the hyphen?

HTML:

```
<head>
<title>Column Combiner</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/global.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr class="tables"></tr>
</table>
<form method="get">
<input id="add" type="button" value="Voeg veld toe">
<input class="combiner" id="combiner" type="text" name="combiner">
<input id="get" name="submit" type="button" value="Combineer">
<div id="values"></div>
</form>
</body>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//add input fields
var field_count = 0;
$('#add').click(function(){
    $('#get').show();
    $('#combiner').show();
    field_count++;
    $('table tr.tables').append('<td><textarea id="textarea" class="inputfield" cols="40" rows="15" name="tname' + field_count + '"></textarea></td>');
});

//connect results with hyphen
$('#get').click(function() {
    $('#values').html('<textarea cols="40" rows="15">' + getCombinedValues() + '</textarea>');
});
});

function getCombinedValues() {
var lines = [];

//split each text field to an array of lines
$('.inputfield').each(function() {
    lines.push($(this).val().split('\n'));
});

//switch rows and columns(horizontal now)
lines = lines.reduce((prev, next) => next.map((item, i) =>
    (prev[i] || []).concat(next[i])
), []);

//combine each line with the combiner value
var combiner = $("input.combiner").val();
lines = $.map(lines, function(e) {
    return e.join(combiner);
});

console.log(lines);

//combine all lines to a single string
return lines.join("\n");

}
```

Comment: You should avoid duplicate IDs: `id="textarea"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check value of textarea with:

```
var myval = $(mytextarea).val()
```

Then check if value have length with a if:

```
if(myval.length > 0){
 //Here your code when have content
}
```